# Date on which maximum number of tasks were completed in a single day django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models like  this. one user can have multiple tasks

```
class User(models.Model):
    userCreated_at=models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

class Tasks(models.Model):
    owner=models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    completion_date_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

So I want to calculate .
**Since time of account creation of user , on what date, maximum number of tasks were completed in a single day**  . Any help would be highly appericiated

Comment: So you want to do this for a *given user* for the `Tasks` of *that* user?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes , like I created a account I am user , so from my account creation date to now on which date I completed most tasks

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem your answer disappear suddenly ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only complete a task after the user is created, you should not worry about the "account creation date"
Instead, doing `Tasks.objects.filter(owner=request.user)` should give you a queryset containing all the tasks.

Finding the date when the most number of tasks were completed by a user will be hard using this data model, but maintaining a table with the same will be easy. Here's how you would do it:

```
class user_max_date(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #Need to import usermodel
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

Now everytime a new task is completed, you have to check if the tasks completed today are more than the max tasks completed. In which case we will update this `max_task_date`

So here's how that would work:

```
today = date.today() #Will require datetime imports
tasksDoneToday = Tasks.objects.filter(owner=request.user).filter(completion_date_time__year=today.year, 
                         completion_date_time__month=today.month, 
                         completion_date_time__day=today.day)

max_date = request.user.user_max_date.date.date()
max_tasks_done = Tasks.objects.filter(owner=request.user).filter(completion_date_time__year=max_date.year, 
                         completion_date_time__month=max_date.month, 
                         completion_date_time__day=max_date.day)
if len(max_tasks_done) < len(tasks_done_today):
    temp = request.user.user_max_date
    temp.date = today
    temp.save()
```

You will need to add this logic to your views.py in the view used to complete the tasks, or you can add a signal that executes this logic.